# Printing without user intervention in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I want to print directly to printer (no user intervention) from a Windows Store App running on a Windows 8 Professional tablet. 
I know it isnt possible to print silently on a pure Windows RT tablet, but is it possible if the Windows store app is running on Windows 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible. Because printing task require user interaction for several reasons like choosing printer, setting height width of page, choosing orientation, showing print preview etc. So WinRT doesn't offer printing support with just a button click.

Comment: Ok, but it is possible to call unmanaged libraries like winspool.Drv and use OpenPrinter, WritePrinter etc. But I dont get anything to print despite no errors when calling these functions.

Comment: I am not sure but those APIs are not supported in WinRT environment. Check this : [Win32 and COM for Windows Store apps (printing and documents)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205760.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The design of Windows Store Apps is to increase security. It isn't the RT tablet that doesn't allow printing silently, it's the RT framework, which is what you have to use as part of all Windows Store Apps.